# Strange error using Data.Map in haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary, ghc

I'm trying to write a really simple editor like "ed".
In this program I'm trying to use a mapping for building the control which translate string-command in actions to perform.
Here's a piece of code:

```
commands :: Map String ([Handle] -> IO ())
commands = fromAscList [
   ("o",\list -> print "Insert name of the file to be opened" >> getLine >>= \nomefile -> 
       openFile nomefile ReadWriteMode >>= \handle -> editor (handle:list)),
   ("i",\list -> case list of { [] -> print "No buffer open" ; handle:res -> write handle } >> editor list),
   ("q",\list -> if list == [] then return () else mapM_ hClose list >> return ())
]

editor :: [Handle] -> IO()
editor list = do
  command <- getLine
  let action = lookup command commands
  case action of
     Nothing  -> print  "Unknown command" >> editor list 
     Just act -> act list
```

The problem is that when I execute the editor function, either in ghci or in an executable file, when I type "o" I get the message "Unknown command" instead of the call to the function to open the file. I've tryed the same code using associative list instead of Map and in this case it works. So what could be the problem here?

What's more odd is that if I call keys on the mapping commands in ghci it return a list containing the string "o" too.

I thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you `import Prelude hiding (lookup)`?  Anyway you should get an error if you didn't.  I don't see the problem yet...  What if you `print command` before the case to make sure no funny I/O stuff is going on?

Comment: Doesn't `getLine` include the trailing newline?

Comment: @luqui yep I did that, anyway I doubt adding a print could change anything, as I said when I give it a "o" command it print "Unknown command" which should be telling that the lookup returned a Nothing, am I wrong?

Comment: @ineff: That definitely happened. But if you `print command`, you know what's actually being looked up. Because your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Ok, I've tryed this is what happen in ghci: after I type o it print in sequences "o" (from the print command) followed by "Unknown command".
Typing "q" make the program terminate, so the rest of the Map works.

Comment: It also works fine for me.  I put the code in a file, load it in GHCi, run `x <- editor []`, and type `o` followed by a newline.

Comment: @ineff You could try altering the buffer mode using `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering`.

Comment: I've just noticed that I've forgotten a piece of code above, the command ("i",...) apparently removing that piece of code make it work, anyway I don't understand why that pair key command should make arise the error, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
commands :: Map String ([Handle] -> IO ())
commands = fromAscList [
   ("o",_),
   ("i",_),
   ("q",_)
]
```

But

```
ghci> Data.List.sort ["o","i","q"]
["i","o","q"]
```

You were lying to `Data.Map`, so it constructed a `Map` that didn't satisfy the required invariants. Thus looking up things in the `Map` didn't work, since the request was sent down the wrong branch (sometimes).

Comment: So, it's just a problem of order thanks a lot, by the way why does the algorithm require the list to be ordered?

Comment: `fromAscList` requires the list to be ordered. If you had used `fromList`, it would have worked. The `Map` can be built more efficiently if the keys are sorted, that's why `fromAscList` and `fromDistinctAscList` exist.